# Unconfirmed Transactions, help please

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions

I sent some bitcoin to another adress, i paid regular fee and it already more than 28 hours that its not confirmed. Can I do anything?
Why does it need that much time to confirm?
On this page (https://bitcoinfees.earn.com/#delay) there was written like 19 hours waiting time. But nothing happened.

Here is my transaction

https://blockchain.info/tx/4c4402a5439fdfcf2cd3d9bbf0c36fbae91a3ce08504da317938eed2d1a125e1

Answer (score 0):

There is not mutch you can do. The easiest solution would be to wait until the transaction confirms.

Your transaction is not eligible for Replace-By-Fee. With RBF it's possible to replace a transaction by nearly the same transaction just with increased fee. To indicate RBF the `sequence` of one of the inputs needs to be lower than `MAX_INT - 1` (in dec: `4294967295 - 1` or in hex: `0xFFFFFFFF - 1`). You can check that for your transaction [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#https://bitaps.com/api/transaction/4c4402a5439fdfcf2cd3d9bbf0c36fbae91a3ce08504da317938eed2d1a125e1).

Since you mentioned that the transaction is to an other address of yours, you could try Child-Pays-For-Parent. This works by spending the unconfirmed transaction output in a new child transaction with much higher fees to pay for the parent transaction and its self. This depends on your wallet software.

[Here would be a guide for Electrum.](https://data-dive.com/unconfirmed-bitcoin-transactions-electrum)

I the end it comes all down to the patience you have. Your transaction will confirm eventually. I would not advice somebody without technical expertise to experiment with different wallets and export/import private keys, just because the transaction does not confirm.

Fee estimation is still a difficult topic, especially in times with many transactions waiting to be confirmed. It's nearly impossible to say that a transaction will confirm in the next 19 hours.